# How to attach EFS volume to Kubernetes PODs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I am using aws EFS volumes to share volume across pods, I am able to mount the volume but mounted volume is not attaching to the pod.

I am getting following error:
**timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod**
**MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-volume" : mount failed: exit status 32**

manifest.yaml file link https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/aws/efs/deploy/manifest.yaml

Comment: Can you share manifest description of pod/deployment. I saw similar error before. What I did is waited some time to attache properly. I see you deployed k8s in aws. Did you use kops?

Comment: @Veerendra, I am not using kops. attaching manifest.yaml. 
I am using efs provisioner library

Comment: What is the host OS of the Node? And are there interesting messages in either the `kubelet` log or the system log?

Comment: @ Matthew L Daniel, host OS is Amazon Linux 2 AMI, I checked the kube-proxy.log file under /var/log, But I don't find any log related to pods attaching to volume

Comment: Not `kube-proxy`, `kubelet`. And does Amazon Linux have an nfs client installed: can you mount the EFS volume at all (not through Kubernetes but just using `mount -t nfs ...`)?

Comment: I just noticed this is effectively a duplicate of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51562179/225016); why didn't you follow up on that thread rather than asking the question again?